ruby-on-rails docker image 632mb
I have done multistage dockerization of my rails app but the image size is over 600mb which is too high.
Dockerfile
# Dockerfile for local development.

# Default Ruby version for this project.
ARG RUBY_VERSION=3.1.0

# Base image
FROM ruby:$RUBY_VERSION-alpine AS base

# Set environment variables for the username,
# app directory, and the language.
ENV USER app
ENV APP_DIR /app

# Set env variables for dev
ENV BUNDLER_VERSION 2.3.3
ENV GEM_HOME=/usr/local/bundle
ENV BUNDLE_PATH=$GEM_HOME
ENV BUNDLE_APP_CONFIG=$BUNDLE_PATH
ENV BUNDLE_JOBS 4
ENV BUNDLE_RETRY 3
ENV RAILS_ENV development
ENV RACK_ENV development
ENV PATH=$APP_DIR/bin:$PATH
ENV LANG C.UTF-8

# Add PostgreSQL, timezone libraries,
# and git for development.
RUN apk add --no-cache --update \
      libpq-dev \
      tzdata \
      git \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

# Start building a new image called "dependencies"
# from the "base" image.
FROM base AS dependencies

# Add libraries required for installing gems.
RUN apk add --no-cache  --update \
      build-base \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

# Copy the Gemfile and Gemfile.lock
# files to the current directory.
COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./

# Install bundler with specified version.
RUN gem install bundler -v $BUNDLER_VERSION

# "frozen" option means that the exact versions of gems
# specified in the Gemfile.lock file will be used,
# and any updates to those gems will be ignored.
#
# Install gems with ENV options from above,
# remove unnecessary files from gems.
RUN bundle config --global frozen 1 && \
    bundle install && \
    rm -rf $BUNDLE_PATH/cache/*.gem && \
    rm -rf $BUNDLE_PATH/ruby/*/cache && \
    find $BUNDLE_PATH/gems/ -name "*.c" -delete && \
    find $BUNDLE_PATH/gems/ -name "*.o" -delete

# Start building a new image from the "base" image.
FROM base

# Copy entrypoint, make it executable.
COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]

# Add new user in the system.
RUN adduser -D $USER

# Create directory for rails application,
# set user as the owner.
RUN mkdir -p $APP_DIR && \
    chown $USER $APP_DIR

# Set the working directory to the app directory.
WORKDIR $APP_DIR

# Switch from root to specified user.
USER $USER

# Copy the bundle directory from the "dependencies"
# image and copy all files to the current directory,
# setting the ownership to the specified user.
COPY --from=dependencies $BUNDLE_PATH $BUNDLE_PATH
COPY --chown=$USER . ./

# Expose port 3000 for the application.
EXPOSE 3000

# Run the command to start the Rails server.
CMD ["rails", "s", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]

How do I make changes to reduce the size of the image?

Start out with a slimmer base or start ripping things out you don't need -- but 632 MB is not huge.

@dbugger ruby:$RUBY_VERSION-alpine is as slim as it gets for ruby images and it's only 40MB. The issue comes from somewhere else. But I do agree, that etranz needs to start removing things one by one and figure out what makes it big. Once you know what the main offenders are, you can start looking into if you really need them or not.

As it stands this question is impossible to answer as we have no idea what you are installing or if you need it and as such we can't help you reduce the image size.

@engineersmnky the program displays basic hello world. I am not installing any package

You can use libpq instead of libpq-dev.
Use docker history image to check which layer is larger and try to optimize for that layer.
But I think your bundle layer takes up most of the capacity.
reference：

https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/main/s390x/libpq-dev
https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/main/x86/libpq

